# Powershell Get-Job Format-Table calculated property

Tags: powershell, properties, formattable

I have some jobs, and I want a nice output. Currently using this:

```
Get-Job | Format-Table -Property name, state, @{n = 'Started'; e = {$($_.psbegintime).tostring("HH:mm:ss")}}, @{n = 'Completed'; e = {$($_.psendtime).tostring("HH:mm:ss")}}
```

---

I'd like create one more column with `n = 'Elapsed'`.
If the job is running, it should calculate

```
$(get-date) - $_.psbegintime
```

if the job is completed, then it should calculate

```
$_.psendtime - $_.psbegintime
```

I tried `$(if ($_.state -ieq "running") {$(get-date) - $_.psbegintime} {$_.psendtime - $_.psbegintime})`, but it has weird output: `{00:00:05.0532890, $($_.psendtime - $_.psbegintime)}`.
I thought I could replace the `$_.psendtime` cause of the `null` value (`($_.psendtime, get-date)[0]`), but I've failed again.

Thanks your help!

Comment: "else" is missing.

Comment: I'm ashamed... I was so tired. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As @rokumaru points out, you're missing the `else` block in the expression so you're returning a `scriptblock` instead of the result of a calculation ***plus*** the `if` statement result if it was successful.

I suggest you break out your code to make it more readable (especially if it's in a script):

```
#requires -Version 4

$prop = @{
    'PipelineVariable' = 'job'
    'Property'         = @(
        'Name', 'State'
        @{ Name = 'Started'; Expression = { $job.PSBeginTime.ToString('HH:mm:ss') } }
        @{ Name = 'Completed'; Expression = { $job.PSEndTime.ToString('HH:mm:ss') } }
        @{
            Name       = 'Elapsed'
            Expression = {
                if ($job.State -eq 'Running') {
                    ((Get-Date) - $job.PSBeginTime).ToString('HH:mm:ss')
                }
                else {
                    ($job.PSEndTime - $job.PSBeginTime).ToString('HH:mm:ss')
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
Get-Job | Format-Table @prop
```

---

#### [`about_CommonParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-6#common-parameter-descriptions): See `PipelineVariable`

#### [`about_Splatting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6#splatting-with-hash-tables)

#### [`Calculated Properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6#parameters): See the `Property` parameter.